# How can I send Local notifications within a given time period on user selected days in swift

Tags: swift, notifications, localnotification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3oWk.png)

I want to send local notifications between 10A.M to 10P.M repeating every 2hours(user input) for the user selected days.

```
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 10
    dateComponents.minute = 00
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    var dateStart = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)
    var dateComponent = DateComponents()
    dateComponent.hour = 22
    dateComponent.minute = 00
    var dateEnd = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponent)

      while dateStart < dateEnd {
     //Add repeating hours start time
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.txtField.text, forKey: "hoursSendary")
        let Nohours = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hoursSendary")
      dateStart = dateStart?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(Nohours * 60 * 60))
        //Schedule notification With body and title.
    scheduleNotification(body: "Free your eyes", titles: "Screen Alarm",day: 1)
    }

func scheduleNotification( body: String, titles:String,day:Int) {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(self.txtField.text, forKey: "hoursSendary")
       let Nohours = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hoursSendary")
       let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:TimeInterval(Nohours * 60 * 60) )

       var components = DateComponents()
       components.weekday = day// sunday = 1 ... saturday = 7
       components.weekdayOrdinal = 10
       components.timeZone = .current
       components.hour = Nohours
       let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
       let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
       content.title = titles
       content.body = body
       content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
       content.categoryIdentifier = "ScreenAlarm"
       let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "NotificationAt-\(date))", content: content, trigger: trigger)
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
         if let error = error {
           print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
         }
       }
     }
```

How can I pass the user selcted days, I have a collection view with days and I'm doing this stuff inside the didselect method.

Comment: just fire local notification with date matching property

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed can you please have a look on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73152344/how-to-send-local-notifications-daily-between-start-time-and-end-time-with-a-giv

Comment: yes in that answer the person firing notification on some date

Comment: what issue you have facing ? can you tell me in detail? you can contact over Facebook

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I have two date pickers giving start time and end time I want to trigger notifications between those two times and have repeat it every day.Did you get it?

Comment: yes I got it but let suppose a starting time is 7:00 am and ending time is 10:00 am so how many notification you want to fire in these 180 mins ?